# Logging into the Android App using Google

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, android-app

Last night I decided to upgrade my phone to Android 6.0 and noticed i am unable to log into the app anymore.

I have always used Google as my login for the site and I was logged into the app just yesterday, before upgrading to 6.0.

I double checked that I don't have a password associated with my account by using the "forgot" link and did get back a confirmation email saying that I don't have a password accociated with my account and that I can login using my Google account.

Yet this is what my login screen looks like on my 6.0 phone.

[[image: Android 6.0 Login Screen]

And on my 5.1.1 tablet it looks like this.

[image: With Android 5.1.1]

Looks like a new permission issue.

Comment: @Kendra yes, not really related, though for completion I just tested both my phone and tablet login using google in Chrome 45 and it works perfectly for me.

Comment: Wait- Did you try clicking the "log in using another open id" button, and try logging in with Google that way? I just realized I read your question incorrectly.

Comment: That does not include Google, (Yahoo!, LJ, WP, Blogger (still not google) Verisign, AOL and Manual Open ID)

Comment: Did you try using the manual open id option? Or is your bug here just that the Google option doesn't appear? The first couple of times I read your post, I took it to mean that you couldn't log in period on your phone through the app, not that the button for Google was missing. If it's just the button missing, consider [edit]ing your question to make that clearer.

Comment: I cannot log in on the phone since the "Login using Google" button does not exit. I can't find the OpenID endpoint for Google accounts, though I did try a few but all of that is besides the point, I can login using my Google account on my 5.1.1 device (since the "Login using Google" button does exists). So my bug would be... I can't log in on my 6.0 phone _and_ the google button does not exist.

Comment: After doing a little more search, I found [this question on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256776/how-do-i-add-a-google-openid-login) that pretty well agrees with your last comment- Google OpenId apparently does not exist anymore, so you do need the button to login via Google. So yeah, you're right, your bug report is kinda both, since the missing button prevents your login.

Comment: Now that you bring that up, I should have really posted this on MSE not here since at affects all sites. I think I'll just repost this there.

Comment: Make sure to include anything relevant from the comments here, to keep from rehasing the discussion on the question there! (You should be good to just delete this one and repost it there, since this has no answers on it and the comments should probably be cleaned up.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed as of version 1.0.83. Android 6.0's new permission model took us a while to change to, since it required lots of changes.